# Hard drive keeps spinning down and up ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive

For some reason my main 1tb barracuda drive started to just spin down and back up again every 20 or so seconds. In the **Disks** application I see *zzz* appear next to the drive and when it spins up it disappears.

I already checked the spindown and standby values and set both to never. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the standby value was set to never but it was not actually set to **on**. Not it works.